# How Can I Convert Pdf File to Text

Tags: android, file-manager, pdf-reader

I would like to select a pdf file from file manager in android and convert it to text so text to speech can read it. I'm following this documentation from android developer site; however, this example is for opening a text file. I'm using PdfReader class/ library in order to open the file and convert to text. but I don't know how to integrate that with Uri.
Here's the code I need to convert from pdf to text using PdfReader

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(file.getPath());
stringParser = PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfReader, 1).trim();
pdfReader.close();
```

I'm calling file manager using intent so the user can select a pdf file

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
      intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
      intent.setType("*/*");
      startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
   }
});
```

then I'm getting uri and opening file

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent resultData) {
        if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if(resultData != null) {
                Uri uri = resultData.getData();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, filePath , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                readPdfFile(uri);
            }
        }
    }

    private String readTextFromUri(Uri uri) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try (InputStream inputStream =
                     getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                     new InputStreamReader(Objects.requireNonNull(inputStream)))) {
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
```

Comment: `readPdfFile(uri);` ??? You did not post code for readPdfFIle(). Nor did you tell where and how you called the posted functions. For instance you did not tell in which way you use PdfReader.

Comment: @blackpos read the post all information is there. pdfreader code goes inside readTextFromUri that method is parsing a text file. I need to modify so it parses a pdf instead

Answer (score 1):

use this
Gradle :-

```
implementation 'com.itextpdf:itextg:5.5.10'
```

```
try {
      String parsedText="";
      PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(yourPdfPath);
      int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
      for (int i = 0; i <n ; i++) {
           parsedText   = parsedText+PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i+1).trim()+"\n"; //Extracting the content from the different pages
      }
      System.out.println(parsedText);
      reader.close();
   } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SyncPdfTextExtractor {
  // TODO: When you have your own Premium account credentials, put them down here:
  private static final String CLIENT_ID = "FREE_TRIAL_ACCOUNT";
  private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "PUBLIC_SECRET";
  private static final String ENDPOINT = "https://api.whatsmate.net/v1/pdf/extract?url=";

  /**
   * Entry Point
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO: Specify the URL of your small PDF document (less than 1MB and 10 pages)
    // To extract text from bigger PDf document, you need to use the async method.
    String url = "https://www.harvesthousepublishers.com/data/files/excerpts/9780736948487_exc.pdf";
    SyncPdfTextExtractor.extractText(url);
  }

  /**
   * Extracts the text from an online PDF document.
   */
  public static void extractText(String pdfUrl) throws Exception {
    URL url = new URL(ENDPOINT + pdfUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
    conn.setRequestProperty("X-WM-CLIENT-ID", CLIENT_ID);
    conn.setRequestProperty("X-WM-CLIENT-SECRET", CLIENT_SECRET);

    int statusCode = conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("Status Code: " + statusCode);
    InputStream is = null;
    if (statusCode == 200) {
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        System.out.println("PDF text is shown below");
        System.out.println("=======================");
    } else {
        is = conn.getErrorStream();
        System.err.println("Something is wrong:");
    }

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)); 
    String output;
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);
    }
    conn.disconnect();
  }

}
------------------------------------

Copying above code follow below Steps-

Specify the URL of your online PDF document on line 20.
Replace the Client ID and Secret on lines 10 and 11 if you have your own credentials.
```